# youtube api json url

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube

I am starting a little jquery plugin for a youtube playlist and I am having problems constructing the URL properly

this is my code:

```
var playlist = {
    playlist: '**',
    apiKey: '**',
    container: $('#test'),
    shuffle: false
}

function player() {
    var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=$'+playlist.playlist+'&key=$'+playlist.apiKey+'&callback=?';
    console.log(url);
    $.getJSON(url, function(result){
        $.each(result, function(){
            $('#test').append();
        });
    });
}
```

and this is what the url above returns:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalidParameter","message":"Invalid value for parameter callback: ","locationType":"parameter","location":"callback"}],"code":400,"message":"Invalid value for parameter callback: "}}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put on the callback a function to execute. If you don't want anything you can just put false like this `&callback=false`. On your code it will be like this:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=$'+playlist.playlist+'&key=$'+playlist.apiKey+'&callback=false';
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Why you putted the `callback=?` and extra `$` before the variables. I just used your credentials and get back the `json` response data.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=PLoyiiz-eZk1WRfVo0JR8YyRiYhuJBwkaY&key=#######

**N.B:** Don't expose your `key` for public usage.